# click back twice after add product on woocomerec

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

when I add a product to the cart by clicking on (add to cart button)on singal product page  and I want to go back to the product list I must to click on the back twice from the browser
my website is (ashjarshop.com)

many thanks

Comment: If you want to go back to the shop page (product list?) you can just click on the shop item in the nav bar at the top.

Comment: Products list (the shop)

Comment: I want from browser  because the customer will do it

Comment: The shop item is available in the nav bar at the top on all front end pages.

Comment: If the customer on page 80 from 100 when click shop item will go to page 1

Comment: I understand. I don't know the answer to your question.